# What does just plain "Low quality" mean in the 10k flag queue? (as opposed to "very low quality")

Tags: support, flags, 10k-tools, low-quality-posts

I just saw this in the flag queue:

---

[image: screenshot]

**What does "Low quality" mean?** Usually it is shown as "very low quality"; for example:

---

[image: screenshot]

---

The flag name is "very low quality" too, so this is unexpected. What does it mean?

Comment: It appears that user somehow entered a custom reason while casting a standard very low quality flag... Maybe if you type something in the "other" box and then select VLQ it still uses that custom text?

Comment: @animuson Hmm... very odd

Comment: … Doorknob, could you try that on this question?

Comment: And what about, "very, very low quality"?

Comment: @minitech Ok, whenever you're ready

Comment: @Doorknob: Go ahead :)

Comment: @minitech [That reason isn't there for some reason on this question](http://i.imgur.com/vnph2jp.png)...?

Comment: Dang, it’s your own question. Pick one of mine.

Comment: @minitech [Ummm...?](http://i.imgur.com/p1kVZr4.png) Maybe there's no VLQ on meta

Comment: Oh. I think it has something to do with votes. Uhh. Flag [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17865913/707111). :D

Comment: @minitech Ok, I typed `This is a test for http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198365/180276` in the "other" box and then switched to VLQ and clicked "flag."

Comment: Thanks — it came through as a regular VLQ.

Comment: @minitech Hmm, so something weird is happening.

Comment: (for future reference: http://i.imgur.com/7L8n160.png)